# $a>0$ and $a\geq 0$ - is this a contradiction?

Tags: logic

I have a very, very elementar question.

If the assumption is that $a>0$ and then in a proof it is shown that $a\geq 0$, is that a contradiction?

Comment: No, $a > 0$ and $a \geq 0$ are compatible. It would be a contradiction if $a\leq 0$ were shown.

Comment: $\geq$: Greater than **or** equal to; if one of those is true, the statement is true.

Comment: What if I told you the answer to your question was "yes" ?  Would you believe me?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

It's only a contradiction if $a=0$. In other words, if your proof can deduce $a=0$, it's a contradiction. Afterall, $1>0$ and $1\geq 0$ is ok. But if in the course of a proof you get $1=0$, then something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$a\geqslant0$ means $a=0\:\vee\:a\gt0$. If you are given that $a\gt0$ as being true then the statement $$a\gt0\:\wedge\:(a=0\:\vee\:a\gt0),$$ is also true since $a=0\:\vee\:a\gt0$ is true. (Why? Remember when $p\vee q$ is true.)